# Avoid change of figure size when adding plot() to imshow()

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, color-mapping

I want to add a line with `plot()` to a color map made with `imshow()` in matplotlib,
where several sub-figures of different sizes are assumed. When adding a line,
the color map somehow changes size. How do I get around this?

Here is a simple example illustrating the problem:

```
import scipy.stats       as stat
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm     as cm
import numpy             as np

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 4))
plt.axes([.05,.1,.4,.8])
data = stat.uniform.rvs(size=2400).reshape((40,60))
plt.imshow(data,cmap=cm.jet,vmin=0,vmax=1)
plt.colorbar(fraction=.03)
plt.plot(range(60),20*np.ones(60),'w-',lw=3)  #  <-- causing problems
plt.title('the damn white line')
```

Comment: Disable the autoscale, or set it to 'tight', before plotting, see:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16157180/how-to-remove-padding-border-in-a-matplotlib-subplot-solved/16162912#16162912

Comment: As mentioned by @RutgerKassies, you can avoid this with the command `plt.autoscale(False)`. Also, in my opinion, it would be a better solution to use `plt.axhline(y=20, c='w', lw=3)` rather than `plt.plot(range(60),20*np.ones(60),'w-',lw=3)`, as the [`axhline`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.axhline) spans the whole horizontal extent of the axes, even if you pan/zoom in the plot.

Comment: @nordev You should post that as an answer

Comment: @user1227298 If you found a work-around you should also post it as an answer

Comment: @nordev, this was just an example. the actual plot has a real curve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid this with the command `plt.autoscale(False)` after the first plot.

Also, in my opinion, it would be a better solution to use [`plt.axhline`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.axhline) rather than `plt.plot` to make a horizontal line, as the `axhline` spans the whole horizontal extent of the axes, even if you pan/zoom in the plot.

In other words, your example could be rewritten like this:

```
import scipy.stats       as stat
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm     as cm
import numpy             as np

data = stat.uniform.rvs(size=2400).reshape((40,60))

plt.figure(figsize=(12, 4))
plt.axes([.05,.1,.4,.8])
plt.imshow(data,cmap=cm.jet,vmin=0,vmax=1)
plt.colorbar(fraction=.03)
plt.autoscale(False)
plt.axhline(y=20, c='w', lw=3)
plt.title('the damn white line')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simple alternative solution: Changing the order of imshow() and plot()

```
import scipy.stats       as stat
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm     as cm
import numpy             as np

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 4))
plt.axes([.05,.1,.4,.8])
data = stat.uniform.rvs(size=2400).reshape((40,60))
plt.plot(range(60),20*np.ones(60),'w-',lw=3)  #  <--- mow before imshow()
plt.imshow(data,cmap=cm.jet,vmin=0,vmax=1)
plt.colorbar(fraction=.03)
plt.title('the damn white line')
```

Output is the same as for nordev's answer.