# Matplotlib scatter plot - Remove white padding

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization, scatter-plot

I'm working with matplotlib to plot a variable in latitude longitude coordinates. The problem is that this image cannot include axes or borders. I have been able to remove axis, but the white padding around my image has to be completely removed (see example images from code below here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHCPF.jpg) .

I have tried several methods from Google searches, including these StackOverflow methodologies:

[Remove padding from matplotlib plotting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11637929/remove-padding-from-matplotlib-plotting)

[How to remove padding/border in a matplotlib subplot (SOLVED)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16157180/how-to-remove-padding-border-in-a-matplotlib-subplot-solved)

[Matplotlib plots: removing axis, legends and white spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9295026/matplotlib-plots-removing-axis-legends-and-white-spaces)

but nothing has worked in removing the white space. If you have any advice (even if it is to ditch matplotlib and to try another plotting library instead) I would appreciate it!

Here is a basic form of the code I'm using that shows this behavior:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
from scipy import stats

lat = np.random.randint(-60.5, high=60.5, size=257087)
lon = np.random.randint(-179.95, high=180, size=257087)
maxnsz =  np.random.randint(12, 60, size=257087)

percRange = np.arange(100,40,-1)
percStr=percRange.astype(str)
val_percentile=np.percentile(maxnsz, percRange, interpolation='nearest')  

#Rank all values
all_percentiles=stats.rankdata(maxnsz)/len(maxnsz)
#Figure setup
fig = matplotlib.pyplot.figure(frameon=False, dpi=600)
#Basemap code can go here

x=lon
y=lat

cmap = matplotlib.cm.get_cmap('cool')


h=np.where(all_percentiles >= 0.999)
hl=np.where((all_percentiles < 0.999) & (all_percentiles > 0.90))
mh=np.where((all_percentiles > 0.75) & (all_percentiles < 0.90))
ml=np.where((all_percentiles >= 0.4) & (all_percentiles < 0.75))
l=np.where(all_percentiles < 0.4)

all_percentiles[h]=0
all_percentiles[hl]=0.25
all_percentiles[mh]=0.5
all_percentiles[ml]=0.75
all_percentiles[l]=1

rgba_low=cmap(1)
rgba_ml=cmap(0.75)
rgba_mh=cmap(0.51)
rgba_hl=cmap(0.25)
rgba_high=cmap(0)

matplotlib.pyplot.axis('off')

matplotlib.pyplot.scatter(x[ml],y[ml], c=rgba_ml, s=3, marker=',',edgecolor='none', alpha=0.4)
matplotlib.pyplot.scatter(x[mh],y[mh], c=rgba_mh, s=3,     marker='o', edgecolor='none', alpha=0.5)
matplotlib.pyplot.scatter(x[hl],y[hl], c=rgba_hl, s=4, marker='*',edgecolor='none', alpha=0.6)
matplotlib.pyplot.scatter(x[h],y[h], c=rgba_high, s=5, marker='^', edgecolor='none',alpha=0.75)

fig.savefig('/home/usr/code/python/testfig.jpg', bbox_inches=0, nbins=0, transparent="True", pad_inches=0.0)
fig.canvas.draw()
```

Comment: Did you read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Nope, but I'll definitely consult that before submitting anything else. @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Thank you for the tip and the answer, I'm learning a lot!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that all the solutions given at [Matplotlib plots: removing axis, legends and white spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9295026/matplotlib-plots-removing-axis-legends-and-white-spaces) are actually meant to work with `imshow`.

So, the following clearly works

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax=fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])
ax.set_axis_off()

im = ax.imshow([[2,3,4,1], [2,4,4,2]], origin="lower", extent=[1,4,2,8])
ax.plot([1,2,3,4], [2,3,4,8], lw=5)

ax.set_aspect('auto')
plt.show()
```

and produces

[image]

But here, you are using `scatter`. Adding a scatter plot

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax=fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])
ax.set_axis_off()


im = ax.imshow([[2,3,4,1], [2,4,4,2]], origin="lower", extent=[1,4,2,8])
ax.plot([1,2,3,4], [2,3,4,8], lw=5)

ax.scatter([2,3,4,1], [2,3,4,8], c="r", s=2500)

ax.set_aspect('auto')
plt.show()
```

produces

[image]

`Scatter` has the particularity that matplotlib tries to make all points visible by default, which means that the axes limits are set such that all scatter points are visible as a whole.

To overcome this, we need to specifically set the axes limits:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax=fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])
ax.set_axis_off()

im = ax.imshow([[2,3,4,1], [2,4,4,2]], origin="lower", extent=[1,4,2,8])
ax.plot([1,2,3,4], [2,3,4,8], lw=5)

ax.scatter([2,3,4,1], [2,3,4,8], c="r", s=2500)

ax.set_xlim([1,4])
ax.set_ylim([2,8])

ax.set_aspect('auto')
plt.show()
```

such that we will get the desired behaviour.

[image]

Comment: @mofs Here you can also see that a minimal example of your problem can be written in 16 lines.