# matplotlib plot to fill figure only with data points, no borders, labels, axes,

Tags: python, matplotlib, layout, plot

I am after an extreme form of matplotlib's tight layout.
I would like the data points to fill the figure from edge to edge without
leaving any borders and without titles, axes, ticks, labels or any other decorations.
I want to do something like what `figimage` does, but for plots instead of raw images.

How do I do that in matplotlib?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @DYZ How do I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Matplotlib plots: removing axis, legends and white spaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9295026/matplotlib-plots-removing-axis-legends-and-white-spaces)

Answer (score 0):

While a solution may be found taking the bits and pieces from an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40726323/matplotlib-scatter-plot-remove-white-padding) it may not be obvious at first sight.

The main idea to have no padding around the axes, is to make the axes the same size as the figure.

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])
```

Alternatively, one can set the outer spacings to `0`.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0, right=1, bottom=0, top=1)
```

Then, in order to remove the axis decorations one can use

```
ax.set_axis_off()
```

or

```
ax.axis("off")
```

This may now still leave some space between the plotted line and the edge. This can be removed by setting the limits appropriately using `ax.set_xlim()` and `ax.set_ylim()`. Or, by using `ax.margins(0)`

A complete example may thus look like

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])
ax.axis("off")

ax.plot([2,3,1])
ax.margins(0)

plt.show()
```

[image]